# global hamburger menu in react-native

Tags: react-native, menu, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I'm trying to implement an element that will act as a hamburger menu to toggle my drawer navigator from all screens. However, my hamburger menu (aka MenuToggle) won't appear in any of my interfaces.   Here are 3 files that can reproduce the problem:

```
// Router.js - the main point of entry for the project

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import Contact from './Contact';

// Router
let Router = 
{
  Contact:{screen:Contact},
}

const Navigator = DrawerNavigator(Router);
export default Navigator;
```

Now here's my contact.js

```
// Contact.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import MenuToggle from './MenuToggle';

class Contact extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {title:"Contact",drawLabel:"Contact"};

  render() {
    return (
      <MenuToggle navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate}/>
    );
  }
}
let Router = 
{
    Contact:{screen:Contact}
}

const Navigator = StackNavigator(Router);
export default Navigator;
```

And here is my MenuToggle.js

```
// MenuToggle.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';


export default class MenuToggle extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }


  render() {
    const style1 =  {
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
    width:40,
    height:40,
    zIndex:20,
    position:'absolute', // comment out this line to see the menu toggle
    top:5,
    right:-80,
    };
    const style2 = {
        backgroundColor:'yellow',
    }
    return (
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this.props.navigate('DrawerOpen')} style={style1}>
            <View style={style2}></View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

My MenuToggle.js never shows up in the contact screen.  If however I comment out `position:absolute`, then it will appear a underneath my header and a little on the left.  But I need it to appear in the top right of the screen overlaid on top of the header.

How do I get this hamburger menu to appear on all screens at the top right?

Comment: What if you wrap the TouchableHighlight in a View and apply style1 to that View?

Comment: @coderhacker thanks I tried that, but same issue.  Something about position absolute prevents the View from appearing as well.

Comment: One more thing. I have had issues with alignment with TouchableHighlight. Not the correct thing but try using TouchableWithoutFeedback, to see if its issue with TouchableHighlight and can move forward from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug.  I accidentally set the `right:-80` making the element out of view.  I made it `right:80` and then the menu item became visible.